# Optimizing DrawRect: for a Snake sort of game

Tags: ios, iphone, optimization, drawrect

I'm trying to create a game that uses kind of snakes. So far I got it to work, it works nicely but after some time it gets kinda laggy, especially on the Iphone 5 and lower.

I know it's because of drawrect:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    CGFloat rr, rg, rb, ra;
    [redcolorr getRed:&rr green:&rg blue:&rb alpha:&ra];
    CGFloat gr, gg, gb, ga;
    [greencolorr getRed:&gr green:&gg blue:&gb alpha:&ga];
    CGFloat br, bg, bb, ba;
    [bluecolorr getRed:&br green:&bg blue:&bb alpha:&ba];

    if ([myName isEqual:@"Server"]) {
        for (int i= 0; i<ServerBody.count; i++) {
            Snake *a;
            a = [ServerBody objectAtIndex:i];

            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, rr, rg, rb, ra);
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(a.x,a.y,7.5*k*sizee, 7.5*k*sizee));
            UIGraphicsPopContext();
        }

    }
    else{

        for (int i= 0; i<IntelligentServerBody.count; i++) {
            Snake *a;
            a = [IntelligentServerBody objectAtIndex:i];

            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, rr, rg, rb, ra);
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(a.x, a.y, 7.5*k*sizee, 7.5*k*sizee));
            UIGraphicsPopContext();
        }
    }
    if ([myName isEqual:@"Client0"]) {
        for (int i= 0; i<Client0Body.count; i++) {
            Snake *a;
            a = [Client0Body objectAtIndex:i];
            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, br, bg, bb, ba);  // white color
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(a.x, a.y, 7.5*k*sizee, 7.5*k*sizee));
            UIGraphicsPopContext();
        }
    }
    else{

        for (int i= 0; i<IntelligentClient0Body.count; i++) {
            Snake *a;
            a = [IntelligentClient0Body objectAtIndex:i];

            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, br, bg, bb, ba);  // white color
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(a.x, a.y, 7.5*k*sizee, 7.5*k*sizee));
            UIGraphicsPopContext();
        }

    }
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
}
```

Keep in mind that :

1. drawrect is called every 0.05 seconds to redraw both snakes
2. there is a server, first iphone, and a client, second iphone (multipeer)

So now, please tell me if im not missing lines of code, or there are unnecessary lines.
Is there any other way to draw the Snakes? I'd like the snake to "shine" ( changing the color at every draw) and maybe to "grow/shrinken" (changing the size of the drown dots.

Comment: Well the `UIGraphicsPush/Pop` calls are redundant for one.. although as `drawRect:` doesn't leverage the GPU, it will always be a bit laggy when called this frequently. You should probably look into trying to re-create the effect you want using [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead, as both leverage the GPU, so will be more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really want to use repeated draw calls like this, you are creating a graphics context on every refresh interval. For example, you might be able to get much better results by creating small "segments" for each snake and then rendering them via composition of segments using SpriteKit. That way, each segment is a GPU texture that gets rendered in an optimal way. You would need to write code to connect segments using X,Y coords and angles instead of this draw logic, it would take some refactoring but that would make better use of the graphics subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use Paths, and it's super effective:

```
    -(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{       
        a = [ServerBody objectAtIndex:0];
         CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 7.5*k*sizee);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, a.x, a.y);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, redcolorr.CGColor); 
        for (int i= 0; i<ServerBody.count; i++) {
            a = [ServerBody objectAtIndex:i];
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx,a.x, a.y);
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Now the question is if I can increase the gameloop timer. I'm using Multipeer Connectivity to send positions every 0.05 seconds from one iPhone to the other. But im sending this :

```
    NSMutableArray *Messagee = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
        [Messagee addObject:x];
        [Messagee addObject:y];
        [Messagee addObject:ang];
        [Messagee addObject:ind];


        NSData* Message = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Messagee];
        [self.partyTime sendData:Message
                        withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable
                           error:nil];
```

And it takes some time to be recieved by the other iPhone, unfortunately.
Is my packet too big?
Should i use Streams to send positions more quickly ?
Other suggestions ?

Thanks for all your answers!